# Change Font Awesome's icon color with hover

Tags: html, css, colors, hover, font-awesome

I just started programming and i need some help.

I'm using Font Awesome icons and i'm trying to change it's color when hovered but don't know why it isn't working. I looked up for other people having the same problem here, tried their solutions but it's still not working :(

here's part of my HTML code:

```
        <footer>
        <div class="row container">
            <div class="logo-rodape col-md-2">
                <img src="img/logo-principal-white-gota.png" alt="Logo Picada Zero">
            </div>

            <div class="r-content col-md-4">
                <p class="slogan-title">CLEAN AND PROTECTION</p>
                <p class="slogan-sub">Proteção e limpeza para sua família</p>
            </div>

            <div class="r-social col-md-5">
                <a href="www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#fff"></i></a>

                <a href="www.vimeo.com"><i class="fa fa-vimeo fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#fff"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </footer>
```

And here's all my footer's CSS:

```
footer{
background: url(../img/rodape-background.png);
clear: both;
padding: 50px 0;
}

footer .container{
position: relative;
margin-left: 80px;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-top: 50px;
}

.logo-rodape {
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline-block; 
}

.r-content {
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-top: 20px;
}


.slogan-title {
font-family: "avenir next condensed";
font-size: 0.3em;
font-size: calc(0.3em + 1vw); 
@include screen-above(800px) {
    font-size: 0.4em;
}
font-weight: 600;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
margin-bottom: -2px;
color: #fff; 
}

.slogan-sub {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-size: 0.2em;
font-size: calc(0.2em + 1vw); 
@include screen-above(800px) {
    font-size: 0.3em;
}
font-weight: 300;
letter-spacing: 1px;
color: #fff;
}

.r-social {
text-align: right;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-left: 60px;
}

.fa-facebook {
padding-right: 20px;
}

.fa-facebook:hover {
color: #57cdf7;
}
```

I'll be really glad with any suggestions, I tried out everything I know so far and couldn't get it right.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check in your browser console?? Ant error like file not found 404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's because you use inline style. It always has a higher priority. Also you're trying to change style on hover of an `<i>` tag, but you should do this with an `<a>`

Take a look:

```css
a {
  display: block;
}

.test1 {
  color: red;
}

.test1:hover {
  color: #57cdf7;
}

.test2 .fa-facebook:hover {
  color: #57cdf7;
}

.test3 .fa-facebook:hover {
  color: #57cdf7;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="test1">
  <i class="fa fa-vimeo fa-2x">facebook</i>
</a>
<a href="#" class="test2">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x">facebook</i>
</a>
<a href="#" class="test3">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" style="color:green">facebook</i>
</a>
```

I recommend to assign a single class for `<a>` tags of your font awesome buttons, remove inline styles and move it to your css file.

Comment: I tried adding a class to my `<a>` tag before but it didnt work properly, so i think you're right about the inline styles. Although, if i remove the inline style how will i make it stay aligned with the other elements? (anyways thanks a lot for the explanation!)

Comment: You are right m8. This seems to be the issue with fontawesome icons. Bootstrap Glyphicons can be hovered fine when color is inline.

Answer (score 0):

As it is in the anchor tag you should be writing the CSS on hover with anchor tag. `a:hover  .fa-facebook { color: #57cdf7}`

Comment: And we're styling an `<i>`, not the real anchor tag again. I'd say it would be better to assign a class to the `<a>` tags

Comment: tried the `a:hover` but it didnt work and the console shows no errors... Also tried assigning a class to my `<a>` tag like `<a class="facebook-icon">` so `.facebook-icon:hover {  color:#57cdf7}` and got nothing :/

Comment: a:hover  .far,   a:hover  .fas {
    color:white;
 }
 li a  .far , li a .fas  {
   color:red;   
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can use this and check on your browser
for example :

```
i.fa.fa-facebook.fa-2x:hover {
color: red;
background-color: red;
}
```

[image]

Comment: you can use this and work correctly  a i.fa-facebook:hover {
    color: red !important;
}

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it works, yay! Could you explain what the !important did?

Comment: when element has a another color css and you add new color code for that not work . !important means overrite when browser excute on , excuze me for english - i cant write correctly english https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/important-declarations/

Answer (score 0):

```
/* hover state */
 a:hover .far,  a:hover .fas {
    color:white;
 }

/* normal state */
li a  .far , li a .fas  {
  color:red;   
}
```

it work for me.... thanks guy.